# CocoaPods integration with CommandLineTool and Dylib targets

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, afnetworking

For test purposes, I created a new project in Xcode as a Command Line tool (Test), added a dylib target called Networking.

Ran the following commands

**pod init**
In the pod file, under the Networking Target, Removed use_frameworks!
added
**pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'**

**pod install**

After Installation, In BuildPhases of Test CLI, I added Networking dylib. Created a simple method to call  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to test out. Called this method from TestCLI by Importing Networking.h

From Xcode it builds just fine, even archive works just fine from Xcode but when I try to archive from the following command line

**xcodebuild -scheme Test -configuration Production archive -archivePath Test.xcarchive**

I get the following error

> ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
>
> The following build commands failed:  Ld
>   /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Test/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/usr/local/lib/libNetwork.dylib
>   normal x86_64 (1 failure)

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your build command:

xcodebuild -workspace Test.xcworkspace -scheme Test -configuration Production archive -archivePath Test.xcarchive

I think if you don't specify the workspace setting, xcodebuild would be trying to use your project, which would not contain any Pods or the paths needed for linking.

Comment: That did it ! Thanks.. Totally forgot about setting xcworkspace when building it via command line.

Comment: Oh good, I'm glad it works for you now. Would you mind marking this answer as accepted when you have a chance?